# Sublime Text with console input for c++ programs

Tags: c++, gcc, sublimetext2

How can I use console input in SublimeText 2.0.1?
I'v chosen "Tools -> Build System -> C++", and add hello.cpp file to the project:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    int a, b, c;
    std::cout << "Enter: ";
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    c = a + b;
    std::cout << a << '+' << b << '=' << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Build successful, but when I run ("Tools->Run"), the line "std::cin >> a >> b;" is passed and I can't enter the values.
In terminal with g++ it run well.
OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime text 3 - compile program and run in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196077/sublime-text-3-compile-program-and-run-in-terminal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think stdin is supported in Sublime Text, however, you can create a file `stdin.input` and use it under the editor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define SUBLIME

#if defined SUBLIME
#  define ISTREAM ifile
#else
#  define ISTREAM std::cin
#endif

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c;
    std::cout << "Enter: ";
    #if defined (SUBLIME)
      std::ifstream ifile("stdin.input");
    #endif
    ISTREAM >> a >> b;
    c = a + b;
    std::cout << a << '+' << b << '=' << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only error I see is that your missing int c;
And if that doesn't work maybe try return 0; instead of return 1;

Comment: You are right. But my problem with editor "Sublime Text". I'v just copied that's code inaccurately. I will correct my ask. (I mean that my code is compiling with g++ from terminal well)