# How should I create a build system that can take STDIN in Sublime Text 3 under OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, sublimetext3

I'm trying to build a single C++ file that can take STDIN after building so I can test some single examples and see whether the code work. But it seems the default C++ build system won't be able to consume any input from STDIN. Is there a way to create my own build system to fix this issue?

Comment: Why can't you just run your program from the terminal?

Comment: @Praetorian: There's no reason "I can't". I just want to know whether there is a way to run this naturally in Sublime Text.

Comment: @Praetorian: And I don't understand why this gets an upvote as well..

Comment: @Siguza: I don't think this is a duplicate. That solution creates a file input directly.

Comment: @derekhh Possibly because someone agrees with me that this isn't worth wasting time over. The linked duplicate does answer your question - *I don't think stdin is supported in Sublime Text*, and then suggests a workaround. Anyway, I'm not going to close it as a duplicate, hope you find an alternate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ended up using terminal on OS X.

Someone asked this question earlier but I didn't end up trying it
[Sublime Text with console input for c++ programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599066/sublime-text-with-console-input-for-c-programs)